# message queue for processing streams of data

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka, mq

I have streams of input data that I process. Each stream is sent in chunks of data. I can only process the N+1st chunk of data of a stream *i* after I *finished* processing the Nth chunk of data of the same stream *i*. Therefore, parallelization can happen by processing multiple streams at once, but I can never split one stream on multiple workers.

Chunks of one stream are added to the queue in order (although chunks from several streams can be added at the same time).

Most message queues, like RabbitMQ, guarantee ordered delivery when multiple workers operate on one queue. However, to achieve the behaviour I would like, I'd need to restrict the number of workers to 1 for each queue, so that the next chunk is always only processed when the previous chunk was finished. To parallelize, I could create a queue for each stream, or a queue for each worker, and have another process that redirects the streams to the worker queues. In fact, the one-queue-per-worker approach is what I do right now, using RabbitMQ's consistent-hashing and shovels. Of course, in terms of load balancing and dynamic scaling of the number of workers, that is far from ideal.

I've read a lot about Kafka, and how it is designed for time-series data (like logs). Yet, I couldn't figure out how I could apply Kafka - or any other message queue out there - to solve my problem.

I would greatly appreciate some hints on how to best use a message queue for my problem.

Comment: Why don't you push the next chunk only after receiving the delivery acknowledgement of the former chunk to the worker?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Kafka, but you'd have to use some stream identification to hash messages on the Producer side, so that messages from one stream always go to the same partition.
Then, on the Consumer side, you'd have to use the low-level consumer to spawn as much consuming threads as you have partitions, where each thread would consume from a single partition.
That would mean that you always process messages in order within each of your streams.
I haven't yet checked out how Kafka 0.9 Producer works, but there were some changes, so you should probably look into those if you want to use the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, Marko! This sounds identical to the RabbitMQ approach to me, and has the same drawbacks: if one worker gets stuck, all streams in its queue/partition will get stuck, and new ones will continue to be added to its queue.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you meant by that. What would be a "worker" analogy in Kafka?

Comment: A worker is a consuming thead. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you push the next chunk only after receiving the delivery acknowledgement of the former chunk to the worker?  Or some kind of a flag that the former chuck is processed by the worker, flag is set to true & then push the next chunk.

If you need to parallelize work create several queues with unique routing keys, based on routing keys push the chunks to respective queues. And have separate flags for every routing key.

Comment: Pushing the next chunk after the delivery acknowledgement would mean that some process needs to keep track of it, and I was wondering if there's a message queue that does exactly that. Otherwise, if I have to keep track of that, I am basically building my own queue.

Comment: what's the point of having a queue if only a single object goes into it at a time. You can even do this without a queue.

Comment: Let me clarify: I have streams of data, which will queue up. For a computation at step i, I need the result of step i-1. So only one result may be computed at a time, and they must be processed strictly in order. However, new steps can still come in at any time, and they must be queued. There are several possibilities to implement this using a combination of queues, locks and stacks, but I imagine this problem to be somewhat common, so I was wondering if there was a message queue available to it.